# Font Color different from original design (Email newsletter)

Tags: html, css, email, fonts

I have problem with font colors while sending email newsletter from hotmail. While the hotmail keeps the exact font color, gmail and yahoo mail (the receipients) change the white font color to black color thus making the text not readable. How can I keep everything similar to the hotmail in yahoo and gmail?

Comment: Are you using inline CSS or is your css in a style tag in the head of your html?

Comment: http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/ - email clients are notoriously inconsistent in how they render content.

Comment: I used actually header style. Now that I use inline style, it is fine. But outlook 2003 webmail changes all fonts to black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wossen, email clients are inconsistent in reading header styles, try using inline styles for your implementation. Also, here's a set of free templates that should help you design better newsletters, https://github.com/mailchimp/Email-Blueprints.

Answer (score 0):

When you declare colors in html email, you should always use the full hex 6-digit code like this `style="color:#252525;"`.

Gmail is also known to convert hyperlinks that are white or black. A workaround is to instead use 'almost' colors like `#FFFFFE` for white and `#000001` for black.